# Overwrite symbol in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, static-libraries

Is it possible in C/C++ (or, with any compiler) to overwrite a symbol specifically? For example there's a library `a.lib` which contains, besides other functions, the implementation of `foo()`. Now, in my program, I want to replace the implementation of `foo()` with another function, so that any call to `foo()` goes straight to my implementation, rather than the implementation in `a.lib`.

Macros are not an option.

Is this possible without modifieng the source of `a.lib`?

Comment: On Linux, we've got `LD_PRELOAD`. On OS X, try `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`. On Windows: ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, probably.

When you do a static link the linker loads symbols from the library if and only if they are needed. If the program, or an earlier library provides that symbol then it won't be on the "needed" list.

A problem arises if the library defined that symbol in the same "object" as other symbols that are needed. A well designed library has one object per symbol (basically, each function is defined in it's own source file, compiled separately, and added to the library individually). A poorly designed library might have objects (source files) that define several functions at once, and then you have to pull in all of them to get just one. Hopefully you don't have this problem.

For dynamic libraries on Linux systems (and other Unix) things are not so clear. You can define the function, and it might get used by your own callers, but callers within the library might still use the library copy. It's all a bit confusing. On Windows, `.lib` files probably work similarly to Linux's `.a` files, but `.dll` files are quite different beasts, with different ways of being confusing.

Comment: Windows (Visual C++) has explicit support for function-level linking. This means the hack of putting each function in its own source file is not needed.

Comment: This is also true of GCC: the `-ffunction-sections` option does it. However, almost nobody uses that option and anyway there are disadvantages.